# Order a table by another table column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM user 
WHERE sec='1' AND reg_by='".$_SESSION['login_username']."' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $startrow, 30 ";
```

I have another table which stores appointments, it has a column named meet.

How can I sort this query by meet?

Not all data at users are in other table.

Comment: can you please share the fields of second table... if possible please share field of both the tables thanks

Comment: id
def
meet 
admin
name

Comment: grammar fixed

And I think this user meant: sort by instead of order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query. Replace another_table with your original table name :

```
$q = "SELECT u.* FROM user AS u LEFT JOIN another_table AS at ON u.userid = at.userid WHERE u.sec='1' AND u.reg_by='".$_SESSION['login_username']."' ORDER BY at.meet DESC LIMIT $startrow, 30 ";
```

Comment: but this doesnt order row who dont have id at other table. How to order after those who exist?

Comment: Do you mean that some appointments(meet column) are not related to any user?

Comment: So, do you want the records sorted by meet on top and then the records which do not have meet sorted by date?

Answer (score 0):

you can use joining for this like

```
select user.*,meet.* from user left join meet on (meet.userid = user.id) where user.sec='1' AND user.reg_by='".$_SESSION['login_username']."' order by meet.userid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN user
ON meets.userid=user.userid WHERE sec='1' AND reg_by='".$_SESSION['login_username']."'  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $startrow, 30 ";
```